# SwipeRefreshLayout prevent refresh when not pulling down from the top

Tags: android, kotlin, swiperefreshlayout

I have a `SwipeRefreshLayout` embedding a `RecyclerView`

```xml
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/catalog_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

I'd like it to trigger the refresh only when I start pulling down from the top of the scrollable area.

If I'm scrolling though the top of the content, when I reach the top still pulling down, it's not supposed to chain with the refresh, that's another intention.

How can I prevent the refresh to trigger when I didn't start the pull down from the top of the content ? Is there an option for that or do I need to cancel it from the refresh listener in some way ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a listener to the `RecyclerView` to know when the moving state is `DRAGGING` or `IDLE`, and use this to allow the **swipeRefresh** to happen only if the **RV** is **not DRAGGING** by saving the condition in a `Boolean` (i.e. canRefresh), so you know the list is not scrolling, hence, you can refresh.

You can disable the `SwipeRefreshLayout` with `isEnabled = false`, this won't stop the list or its items functionality, just the `SwipeRefreshLayout`

Comment: Understood, I'll try that if there is no native option